# Got an error from unknown thread, /pb2/build/sb_0-13157587-1410170252.03/rpm/BUILD/mysql-5.5.40/mysql-5.5.40/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

I am using mysql 5.5.40-log and my default storage engine is Innodb, I found this error in my error log

> [ERROR] Got an error from unknown thread,
>   /pb2/build/sb_0-13157587-1410170252.03/rpm/BUILD/mysql-5.5.40/mysql-5.5.40/storage/myisam/mi_write.c:226

I Tried to resolve it by setting the `myisam_recover_options=BACKUP` variable but still this error occurred.

How can I resolve it ? can any one explain me why this error occured?

Answer (score 0):

It probably also said  "try to repair it"

From mysql:

```
CHECK TABLE table_name;
REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

Or it can be done from myisamchk.

Recommend switching to InnoDB.